# How to Override Class without Parent Constructor Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, frontend, widget

How to override a class without creating parent constructor?
Actually I'm overriding **Widget** and it works perfectly for 2.2.X versions but for 2.1.X versions it shows me an error **Interceptor::escapeHtmlAttr**
After searching this error I got that this is the version problem so some files are not available in 2.1.X versions so after that I want to override the class without parent constructor,
 How can I do that???

Comment: have you checked this https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/72b192e88250476749b1ab700c19ed0869d3f732#diff-0e10c44d6b0961dcab05891b110d0305R892. `escapeHtmlAttr` is introduced in magento 2.2.x so therefore it give error

Comment: Yeah Brother I know that but I need a generic solution which works on every version of Magento 2